# How to Separate GraphQL Subscriptions alone to another Server

Tags: google-app-engine, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-subscriptions

I'm planning to Apollo-Graphql on Google App Engine (GAE). So I don't have to worry about the scaling (I'll be using Redis or some other pubsub). However, the problem is GAE doesn't support web sockets. I heavily use GraphQL subscriptions.

What Google recommends is to separate web socket into another VM (like Google Compute Engine) and keep the rest inside GAE: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket

Is it possible to do this on Apollo Server? I'm using node js apollo-server-express

Answer (score 1):

It's a good pattern to scale your infra. There is no contraindication to use `apollo-server-express`/Apollo-Graphql.

Use the same code base, one will handle query and mutation with `http` and the other will handle subscribe with `websocket`. Just route correct network to (GAE) or Google Compute Engine.

Every `http` query will be handle by GAE. And apollo-client will subscribe `ws` query on Google Compute Engine. When one event is publish on Redis or other, apollo-graph will consume and resolve only if their is subscriber on `ws`.

So you don't need connect pubsub/Redis on GAE.

I was considering using 2 projects for `http` and `ws` but it won't share graphQL schemas.